# When I edit Android layout it does not appear on device after running

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

For example. If I have line:

```
android:background="@color/first"
```

When I replace it at this:

```
android:background="@color/second"
```

and run this on device which is already installed this application, nothing happens. It helps only manual delete the application from my device and re-install. Why can't I see the changes when I run it from the Android Studio (Shift+F10) if application is already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have enabled instant run in android studio disable it

> Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

or update you android studio version to 2.1.2

Comment: Yes, it works! I already have this version, but only after disabling of instant run my changes were. Thank you!